# Page gone: 404, or other options?

Tags: seo, google

I have a website which is actually a search engine to search through our data.
Each item has its own detailpage, and a search returns a list of matching data, with links to the detailpages.
There are about 10 million items in our database, however, every day several hundreds are removed, and new ones are added. The new ones are no problem, but how should I treat the removed ones? Currently, I'm giving them a status 404, but Google is constantly complaining about this in the webmaster tools.
I was thinking about two options: a 410 (REALLY gone), or make it a redirect (301) to the homepage?

Comment: are you automatically resubmitting a sitemap every day? Also, only use a 301 if it has moved as this allows google to re-index the correct url. If it has being removed completely, show a 410 error

Comment: Currently I'm resubmitting it every 2 months, but I'm about to update it to weekly. Would daily be a better way? Wouldn't it be pushing it too much too Google?

Comment: I updated my previous comment, Also your sitemap should have priority setting. In the case of pushing google, it only works in the same way an RSS feed works, it is automatically created allowing google to quickly spider the new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your content has been removed then simply use the 410 stating that the page did exist however it has been removed. Only use a 301 redirect when you want to tell google that page has moved. If you use these incorrectly this could impact on your SEO quick drastically.

So in my option implement a 410 error message on the pages that have moved.

I would also generate a sitemap automatically and submit this to google. As you have new content google will recognise this and start spidering your content quicker.

If you are unsure about how generating a very substantial sitemap for your site consider creating a master sitemap every month and adding an additional sitemap with the newly added links every day or every couple of days until you manage to create another master sitemap. This way you will be constantly notifying google of changes which they like. See [here](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/giving-you-fresher-more-recent-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

Returning a 404 not found response would normally suffice and in the nature of your website, the amount of these being raised in Google WMT will likely only be temporary whilst they update their index (unless there are other websites linking to these pages that you are removing) so this would not cause a problem.

Alternatively, serving a 410 gone response would also be okay as these pages are permanently gone. A 410 for pages that will never return at that URL in the quantity that you have would be best though.

Either will be reported in Google WMT though yet there only messages as such rather than 'errors' regarding your website. There is no direct negative affect from serving 404's or 410's providing they are used correctly.

You can also read what Google [have to say](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/64033?hl=en) on this.